# Vstack over an empty array

Tags: python, arrays, performance, numpy

Giving this code:

```
import numpy as np
array1 = []

for i in range(10):
    array1 = np.vstack((array1,i))
```

Is there a way to do this without having to treat the first case specifically?
In my real code i have to iterate over 100000 times, so It feels to me that including something like this:

```
import numpy as np
array1 = []

for i in range(10):
    if np.size(array1)==0:
        array1 = np.append(array1,i)
    else:
        array1 = np.vstack((array1,i))
```

would bé a very ineficient way to solve it.

**Is there anyway of making this step more eficient?**

Edit: The code is just a simplifyed version of the code, here im just vtacking simple numbers. In the real code I stack arrays of 2 values so final array gives something like:

```
out_array = [[0.5,0.1],[0.2,0.1],...]
```

Comment: `vstack` is inefficient.  Use list append if need to do it 1000 times.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @wwii this is an example code, the purpose of the real one is to stack features from a text mining function and have an array of features as output. Something like 'output_array = [[0.2,0.1],[0.34 , 0.7], ...]'

Comment: Your 1st code block raises a `ValueError` !!! — I haven't tested the second block.  What do you want to do?  I could try to guess, but it's you that should explain better your intention…

Comment: Do you know how big the final array will be in advance?

Comment: @gboffi Yup, it raises it because you can't vstack [] and [1,2], One way of solving it is with the code in the second block, the question is if there is any  other way to do this.

Comment: Just append to a list and do `np.array([[0.5,0.1],[0.2,0.1],...]) at the end.

Comment: @hpaulj yeah, read your answer in the post you said, thank you!